# Class Blog\Controllers\Article does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When I visit `domain.com/article` I get the error:

```
Class Blog\Controllers\Article does not exist
```

Whats causing this or what am i doing wrong?

`app/controllers/Article.php:`

```
namespace Blog\Controllers;

use View;
use BaseController;

class Article extends \BaseController
{
    public function showIndex()
    {
        return 'index view';
    }

}
```

`app/routes.php:`

```
Route::controller('article', 'Blog\Controllers\Article');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `namespace` and `directory` doesn't matched, put this class inside given path (commented) according to your `namespace` ([psr-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md))

```
// Class Path : "app/controllers/blog/controllers/Article.php"

namespace Blog\Controllers;

use View;
use BaseController;

class Article extends \BaseController
{
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return 'index view';
    }
}
```

Also, notice `getIndex()` not `showIndex()`, [read more on documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers).

Comment: thanks that worked, So when i write Blog\Controllers\Article the blog/controller path needs to exist? Also when a person gives their class a name of blog\controllers for example , is the purpose of it because thats where the (example) article class will reside?

Comment: Welcome! Yes, exactly, `namespace foo\bar\baz.php` should be in `foo/bar/` folder. :-)

Comment: aside from it being a laravel thing, would it be the right by of doing it when dealing with namespaces as recommended by psr-0?

Comment: Yes, this is the `standard` and recommended way.

Comment: got it thanks, would you happen to know of a site that explains psr-0 in more simpler terms, i think i've read it before and didn't comprehend it

Comment: Welcome again and yes, [Search result](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=php+psr-0&rlz=1C1KMZB_enBD539BD539&oq=php+psr&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60l2j0l2.3843j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).